# Applying Regex across entire column of a Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a Dataframe with 3 columns:

```
id,name,team 
101,kevin, marketing
102,scott,admin\n
103,peter,finance\n
```

I am trying to apply a regex function such that I remove the unnecessary spaces. I have got the code that removes these spaces how ever I am unable loop it through the entire Dataframe.

This is what I have tried thus far:

```
df['team'] = re.sub(r'[\n\r]*','',df['team'])
```

But this throws an error `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 're'`

Could anyone advice how could I loop this regex through the entire Dataframe `df['team']` column

Comment: not tested df["team"]=df["team"].str.strip()

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are almost there, there are two simple ways of doing this:

```
# option 1 - faster way
df['team'] =  [re.sub(r'[\n\r]*','', str(x)) for x in df['team']]

# option 2
df['team'] =  df['team'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'[\n\r]*','', str(x)))
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I get an error "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object"

Comment: @hellokee i am not sure what type `team` has, i made a tiny change, can you try now ?

Comment: There is an inbuilt function for the same in Pandas https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html

Answer (score 12):

As long it's a dataframe check replace https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

```
df['team'].replace( { r"[\n\r]+" : '' }, inplace= True, regex = True)
```

Regarding the regex, '*' means 0 or more, you should need '+' which is 1 or more

Comment: Thanks! Is this any faster than using the apply function?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a powerful technique to replace multiple words in a pandas column in one step without loops. In my code I wanted to eliminate things like 'CORPORATION', 'LLC' etc. (all of them is in the RemoveDB.csv file) from my column without using a loop. In this scenario I'm removing 40 words from the entire column in one step.

```
RemoveDB = pd.read_csv('RemoveDBcsv')
RemoveDB = RemoveDB['REMOVE'].tolist()
RemoveDB = '|'.join(RemoveDB)
pattern = re.compile(RemoveDB)    
df['NAME']= df['NAME'].str.replace(pattern,'', regex = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example (but without regex) but maybe still usefull for someone.

```
id = pd.Series(['101','102','103'])
name = pd.Series(['kevin','scott','peter'])
team = pd.Series(['     marketing','admin\n', 'finance\n'])

testsO = pd.DataFrame({'id': id, 'name': name, 'team': team})
print(testsO)
testsO['team'] = testsO['team'].str.strip()
print(testsO)
```