# RegEx string pattern matching in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm a little rusty with my RegEx and hoping someone can help with that should be a fairly simply pattern!

I'm trying to filter a pandas dataframe on a specific column with strings matching the following pattern:

"**GO**XX**P**" *OR* "**BI**XX**P**"

The "XX" in the string can be any 2 letters. The string just needs to start with either "**GO**" or "**BI**", followed by 2 letters, and then end with "**P**".

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can GO and BI have letters before it, and can there be letters after P also?

Comment: For example this will accomplish what you need: /(GO|BI)[a-zA-Z]{2}(P)/

That command would also select the GOXXP in a word like fdsGOXXPcvc

Comment: [regex in pandas framework couloumn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53962844/applying-regex-across-entire-column-of-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex would look like this:

```
/\b(GO|BI)[a-zA-Z]{2}(P)\b/
```

You can test it out here if you are curious: https://www.regexpal.com/